# How can I convert string to boolean?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cc

I have this code:

```
trace(arr[0][2]);
cb.selected = Boolean(arr[0][2]);
```

This outputs "false" but the checkbox is selected. How can I fix this?

Comment: What is arr[0][2]? Is it the String "false"?

Comment: yes, it's a string with value "false"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. You are using [the top level function Boolean](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#Boolean%28%29) / [explicitly converting to a different type](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f87.html).

If the argument is a `non-empty String` it will return `true`.

Why do you have this string in the first place?
Why don't you simply store boolean values?

Comment: thank you for your answer. I thought arrays won't accept booleans. let me try it.

Comment: @nikel they do accept them, just like any other type. You can alternatively define a `Vector` that excepts `Boolean` only.

Answer (score 2):

Check `arr[0][2]` value:

```
cb.selected = arr[0][2] == "true" ? true : false;
```

or simple:

```
cb.selected = arr[0][2] == "true";
```